# Needing some guidance on designing a DB

Tags: database-design

So I am not a coder, clearly. I'm hoping that someone would be kind enough to understand my situation and help me ask the right questions to have a DB designed for my needs.

I currently use Excel to store Property Addresses, Phone Numbers (lots of them) and Names of Persons. Depending on the Sheet, these could easily reach into several thousand unique lines of information.

The issue I have right now, is that Excel is seemingly taking things into its own hands and moving cells up from their original location. This of course is causing serious problems with matching up. I have seen data be off by 1 line up to 8 lines up from its original position. I can't get an explanation from any experts, as to why.

Of course, I have to delete items as they are no longer needed or there are duplicate phone numbers. Every line of data is kept in its own cell, within the same line.

What I need to know is the best and most secure way to store this data and not be worried about it becoming out of alignment, because I delete something. The information needs to be searchable by phone number and be able to delete and move from one sheet or table, without any issues. What should I be asking a developer to create for me?

I obviously don't know the lingo, but if it's explained once, I will be able to follow to a point. Someone mentioned storing the Properties individually and not in lines of data, if that makes sense.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd start by installing Access and importing your data into it. At the very least it will behave as you expect with regard to deletions/additions and "rows" rather than "cells". Excel is not a database!

Comment: Are you hiring a contractor to develop this? Or are you going to attempt this yourself?

Comment: Have you thought about using an off-the-shelf product?  There must be [thousands of products out there that provide a way to manage contacts](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=contact+management+system&t=ffsb&atb=v65-7&ia=web).